# How to upload asp mvc local site to host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hosting, web-hosting

I just want to know what I should do to upload my localhost asp mvc project to the host .. it's the first time I do that and I have no idea which files I should upload , and what is the steps to do that .

if someone have experience with that and could help me , thanks

Note I tried azure and did not like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your application by publishing it to server from Visual Studio. Once, you configure publishing in your visual studio, you can just [publish](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/875/How-to-deploy-Visual-Studio-2010-web-application-project-with-SQL-database-using-Web-Deploy.html) your app using one click. You will have to obain the publishing credential from your hoster.

Another option is [FTP](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/1599/Uploading-files-using-FileZilla.html). What you will need to do is [download/Install](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=win64) FTP client and connect to the server with the FTP details provided by your hoster then upload the contents of root director of your application to the server.